Genexus 17 y WorkwithPlus 15
Hola tengo una kb en Genexus 17 con Gam y Workwithplus 15, en el backoffice he creado un usuario nuevo con un nuevo rol con permisos solo de algunos webpanel para ese usuario creado solo tenga acceso a ellos y nada mas. Tambien he creado un nuevo menu asociados a los webpanels permitidos para el rol creado, pero cuando me logeo con el usuario nuevo creado no me aparece el menu creado, sino que sigue saliendo el menu predeterminado de Workwithplus (Opcion 1, Opcion 2 y Opcion 3). ¿que debo hacer para lograr ver el menu nuevo creado cuando el usuario nuevo se loguea?
